# Create ML Feature column empty on row 0

Tags: coreml, createml

first time Create ML user, I am trying to create an activity classification model for my app. For testing I have created three activities with seven feature columns. All values are integers ranging from -10000 to 10000. When I click on Train Model, I get the following error:

`Feature column xx is empty on row 0 of input data table`

I have CSV files as input with header rows. If I exclude feature column xx the error is on the next column. I'm on Create ML 1.0 (Xcode 11.6).

Any ideas?

Cheers
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Ok, due to the sensor transmission, I had to multiply the sensor data with 1000 to get integers. I created a script to clean up the sensor data by dividing it through 1000 and now my model works.